# How to write a regex to match a Javascript object name?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

For example, consider Javascript object document.I wish to replace the string "document." with "doc." such that:

1. In a case such as xyz.document.abc "document." is **not** replaced.
2. When a variable is of form predocument.xyz "document." is **not** replaced.
3. When there is a case such as document.abc or (document.abc or =document.abc or +document.abc etc "document." is replaced.

Since Javascript does not support look behind regex please suggest an alternative

Comment: I need the cases when the word document be preceded by a "." character or a "\w" character to be excluded

Comment: `([^\w.])document(?=[^\w]|\b)` and replace with `$1doc`. [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wAKvkZ/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though originally posted as a comment, I'll allow myself to post my solution once again as an answer, because I don't want this question to hang somewhere as "open". Also, initially I thought that someone would come with a better solution in a second, but apparently it never happened, so there you go:

```
([^\w.])document(?=[^\w]|\b)
```

and replace with

```
$1doc
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wAKvkZ/1).